# Get correct status in a text box based on date from another text box in a userform

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time posting here and I'm new to VBA.

What I'm trying to achieve is to set the correct membership status from a list of 3 possibilities; Active, Expired or No Payment Made. This is based on the date entered in another text box named 'Paid On'. It's a 12 month membership so:

If the 'Paid On' text box date value entered or showing is < today's date then the 'membership status' text box registers/shows as "active".
If the 'Paid On' text box is > today's date then the 'membership status' text box registers/shows as "expired".
If the 'Paid On' text box is blank then the 'membership status' text box shows/registers "No Payment Made".

The 2 text boxes are part of a DB worksheet in excel, whereby 'membership status' is in column G and 'Paid On' is in column H.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following, it will check the last row with data on Column A and then loop from row 2 to the last checking values on Column H (Paid On) and update Column G (Membership Status) to the appropriate value:

```
Sub UpdateStatus()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DB")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

For i = 2 To LastRow
'loop from row 2 to last row
    If ws.Cells(i, "H").Value = "" Then ws.Cells(i, "G").Value = "No Payment Made"
    'if nothing under Paid On then "No Payment Made"
    If ws.Cells(i, "H").Value < Now() And ws.Cells(i, "H").Value <> "" Then ws.Cells(i, "G").Value = "Active"
    'if Paid On < Today then "Active"
    If ws.Cells(i, "H").Value > Now() Then ws.Cells(i, "G").Value = "Expired"
    'if Paid On > Today then "Expired"
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Xabier, Thank you for your prompt response. In addition, how do I now show the Membership status in the textbox of my userform? Do I need to put "me.membershipstatus.value=(define the value here)".